# Django Rest Framework - PrimaryKeyRelatedField with post_save signal

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I am building an endpoint that uses the PrimaryKeyRelatedField to set the ManyToOne/Reverse Foreign key relationship of the example House model provided below:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=245)
    

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=245)
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, related_name='cars')
```

The serializer uses the PrimaryKeyRelatedField in the following way:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cars = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=models.Car.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.House
        fields = "__all__"
```

I would like to create a signal which, after a house is saved, does something with the related cars. I tried two options:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=models.House)
def post_save_house(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    House is saved before its related Car objects so instance.cars.all() is an unupdated queryset
    """
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    print(instance.cars.all())


@receiver(post_save, sender=models.Car)
def post_save_car(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Car is not saved but updated through queryset.update() so signal does not fire
    """
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    print(instance)
```

However, it seems that when updating a *House* object as well as its related *Car* objects through the *HouseSerializer*, the *instance.cars.all()* queryset still corresponds to the unupdated queryset. I tried refetching the objects from the database and clearing the queryset but that does not seem to be the issue. It seems that the *PrimarykeyRelatedField* first saves the *House* object before updating the related *Car* objects which makes sense when considering that, on creation, a *House* object must exist before attaching a *Car* object to it. Furthermore, the *Car* object does not send a post_save signal (I suspect queryset.update() is used to update the foreign keys?) so listening to post_save signals there also does not work.

With that in mind, how can one create post_save behaviour for setting foreign keys through their reverse accessor?

Comment: First the `House` is updated, and *then* the related `cars`, since we first need to save a `House` before we have a primary key that can be used for new items. You thus should add a signal on the `post_save` of a `Car`, not a `House`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  That is exactly what I explained right? I explained that putting a 
    post_save signal on     House does not seem to work since     House is updated first (like you explain as well) and I explained that putting a     post_save_signal on     Car also does not work because it seems that     queryset.update() is used instead of 
    object.save()

Comment: How about overriding the serializer's save and doing some post-process after calling `super().save()`?

Comment: @bdbd Good point, that would definitely work. I do feel like the Django Rest Framework should have triggered the Car post_save_signal.

Comment: If you look [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L983), it seems that saving the instance comes first before handling the relations (as you observed). But it also seems it doesn't even touch the related model at all (`Car` in this case), just assigning the values of the primary keys to the reverse relation. So that's probably why no signals for `Car` is raised, because the relation is saved through `House`?

Comment: I think you are right. This is giving me quite some trouble unfortunately because there is no (fast) way of knowing which "relations" have been added/deleted. The reason I need this is because I am tracking history through signals.